# Use jQuery datepicker and the Create view not worked correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I use ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor View  and try to use [Scott Allen's way](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) to replace datepicker for DateTime types.
So I have a simple model like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime EnterYear { get; set; }

}
```

before any changes all of the views worked correctly, but when I add some codes to use datapicker I have a problem: Edit view worked correctly, but when I try to go to the create view there is an error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-
null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where 
it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 
'System.DateTime'.

Source Error:
Line 59:         </div>
Line 60:         <div class="editor-field">
Line 61:             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnterYear)
Line 62:             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnterYear)
Line 63:         </div>

Source File: d:\Projects\MyProject\Views\Student\Create.cshtml    Line: 61
```

there is my changes:

1- Add EditorTemplates folder to shared folder in view.

2- Add DateTime Partial view to above folder with:

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue
, new { data_datepicker = true })
```

3- Add new Script to _Layout view:

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {
$(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker();
})
```

4- And add needed script and css references to _Layout:

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

with this implementations the Edit view worked correctly with data picker but the crate view run the error, what happen to Create view? where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue
, new { data_datepicker = true })
```

should be

```
@model System.DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue
, new { data_datepicker = true })
```

to allow for empty text box value